# Why am I seeing more than one explorer running at the Task Manager in my Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Why am I seeing more than one explorer running at the Task Manager in my Win7?

[image]

Comment: Have you done a full system scan?

Comment: This is standard documented behavior for Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

### Because you told it to do this.

Whatever made you think, given that there's a properties setting explicitly for it in the `folder and search options` of Explorer folders, that Windows Explorer *doesn't* use multiple processes?

### Further reading

- Microsoft corporation (2012). [*Change folder options*](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Change-folder-options).  Windows 7 Help.
- Microsoft corporation (2006-11-01). [*How to Run Windows NT Explorer As a Separate Process*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156366).  156366.  Microsoft KnowledgeBase.
- Microsoft corporation (2000). [*DesktopProcess*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc938262.aspx).  TechNet.

Comment: It's stupid to jump straight to that conclusion when this is an ordinary, documented for 10 years, feature of the program that has an easy to find setting on the desktop.  Look at what you have told Explorer to actually do before going into the ever popular "My computer is doing something!  It must be a virus!" mode that so many people foolishly adopt.

Comment: Have you looked to see if that option is checked?

Comment: OK. This is not virus. This is uTorrent download manager's "Go to Directory" command.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same thing happen, but I know it's not a virus. Whenever I switch from Windows Aero to classic, or the other way around, I get extra explorer processes started. Seems to just be a random bug.

Are you sure you aren't having it open folders in their own process? You haven't actually answered that question for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure for Win7, but I know in XP that if you set "run folders in separate processes", this will happen, so it is probably similar. You'll have one instance per open folder.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** its not a sign of Virus then edit your shortcut, and take off any arguments to "explorer.exe".

**Rightclick** drag your **My Computer** icon on the desktop over to a blank space.Create a **shortcut** now **unpin** any **Windows Explorer** you have from your **Taskbar**,drag your **My Computer** shortcut to the **Taskbar**.Now, if you just click this, you go to Libraries..BUT,if instead you **right-click** it, you will see the My Computer shortcut select this and it goes to My Computer,and there are never any more **"explorer.exe's"** hanging around.